# Can't get ruby-gmail gem working

Tags: ruby, gmail

I am trying to use [Ruby-email gem](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail#features)to access my gmail emails and manage them using ruby.I am doing everything correctly as required in the documentation. But then it is giving a error. For example: here is my code

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require 'gmail'
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > gmail = Gmail.new('username', 'password')
 => #<Gmail::Client0x2bbb7f8 (username@gmail.com) disconnected>
```

even when I enter my correct username  and password it is still giving the same error.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have 2 factor authentication on?

Comment: Oh, on my gmail account? nope I dont. I disabled it. Could it be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently. I had to change my gmail settings to allow for less secure apps and it worked. You can find more information at https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
I wouldn't recommend it but I could not find any other working solution.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @ben you are being logged in properly but Google is rejecting the connection. Change your settings and you will be able to log in with the gem.